# Matplotlib scatter graph colour by Y value

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, scatter

I am plotting a scatter graph in matplotlib, I can't figure out how to colour the plots the way i need.

Each Y value needs its own unique colour.

---

my data looks like this :

X [5,5,5,5,5,10,10,15,15,15,15...],

Y [1,2,3,4,5,2,4,1,2,3,4,7...]

Each Y value represents a unique device, and so should be colored uniquely.

---

I have created dictionaries that hold each Y value, along with a hex colour value but not sure if i am going on the right lines

---

Current graph (Lower), so each id value (Y value) would need its own colour :

[image: current graph]

Comment: Share your code and explain your problem so someone can help you

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `PatchCollection` with `Circle`:

```
from matplotlib.patches import Circle, Wedge, Polygon
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection    

# this is a list with all your circles
patch_rs = [Circle(x, y, radius, facecolor='orange', edgecolor='k')]

collection = PatchCollection(patch_rs)
ax1.add_collection(collection)
```

`facecolor` and `edgecolor` can be strings, hex, RGB, etc. (see [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/colors/colors.html)).

[Full example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/api/patch_collection.html)

[Documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Circle.html)

Comment: Thanks, will give that a go 